# Creating embed resource for explorer

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I am trying to embed some icons on my DLL, but somthing is not correct.

Using .NET4 and VS 2010 and Windows7 x64
I have this satellite DLL (Class Library). I Add the Resource file and the my icons.
Inside my DLL code i am able to access the icons.(But this is not the ideia).

The problem is when i try do use this DLL, for example, to choose an icon to my custom folder.
I Click on folder properties, Change Icon, but when i choose my DLL, i get an error saying there is no Icons on my DLL.

I am sure something is missing on my class library to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your icons in a Resource DLL, not a Class Library. See: ["Creating a Resource-Only DLL" at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0.aspx) (i found the said Project Type in Visual C++ > Win32 > Win32 Project).